# error get string to array string & string to array int

Tags: android, arrays, string, android-edittext, int

I am trying to write something like 1 + 1 in the edit text by pressing the app buttons and in converting the intgers to string in order to have them beside the rest of the intger ex: 11 not 1+1 (=2) i am getting error "FATAL EXCEPTION" with this line of code 
when pressing any number button

N[ii] = Integer.parseInt(stringNumber);

also error "FATAL EXCEPTION" in displayCalculations methode on pressing on the Sins x,+,-  buttons

```
private void insertOrCheckNumber() {
    if (End == 0) {
        ii++;
    } else if (u == 0) {
        N = new int[ii];
        stringNumber = stringNumber + String.valueOf(num);
        displayCalculations(stringNumber);
        N[ii] = Integer.parseInt(stringNumber);
    }
    if (u == 1) {
        Sins = new String[iii];
        displayCalculations(Sins[iii]);
    }

}
private void clickNumber(int cN) {
    u = 0;
    num = cN;
    insertOrCheckNumber();
}

private void displayCalculations(String txt) {
    Calcs = String.valueOf(showCalcs.getText());
    showCalcs.setText(Calcs + " " + txt);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your activity**

private ListView listview;

**onCreate**

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);  
ArrayList<> finalN = new ArrayList<y>;
customAdapter = new listAdapter(this,R.layout.listview_example, finalN);
        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

public class listAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<>
        {
            public listAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();

            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi;
                vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listview_example, null);
            }
               //Setting the value to the textfields
            return v;
        }
```

if you want my full code, ask and i'll send it ;)

Comment: thanks but the list works as a string or integer if I used it without the adapter and the list view just as an value ?

Comment: look here, http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html and another example https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/arraylist/arraylist-in-java-example-how-to-use-arraylist/